# "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n... Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000000c)

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, command, rundll32

I stored my printer settings in a .dat file with this command:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "SATO CG408" /a "c:\INI\small-tag.dat
```

I'm then trying to restore the printer setting in VB.net with this command (passing in my ini values).

```
Call Shell("RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n " & """" & My.LabelPrinter & """" & " /a " & """" & My.MediumTag & """")
```

I get the following error: Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000000c).

It works on my developer machine but when I install the application on a client's computer it comes up with that error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use the existing driver on the client's computer. So the command would use the " u " flag.

```
Call Shell("RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n " & """" & My.LabelPrinter & """" & " /a " & """" & My.SmallTag & """" & " u ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "SATO CG408" /a "c:\INI\small-tag.dat d g

RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "SATO CG408" /a "c:\INI\small-tag.dat d g r
```

Save with "d g" and restore with "d g r"

More information is available here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx

Comment: Not if user is not admin and that the user who save the configuration in "Domain Admin".

Comment: In this case, check the user (Domain Users) has the rights he claims.